# Sequences and subsequences convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove or disprove:

> Let $a_n$ sequence, such that for any prime number p, the subsequence $a_{kp}$ is converging, so $a_n$ is necessarily converging.

I tried to find a counter example, such that there are two different sub sequences which converge to different limits, but didn't succeed. I think that the claim is wrong, but can't show it.

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $n_j = (\prod_{i=1}^j p_i) + 1$ for the first $j$ primes $p_i$ and define this special subsequence $a_{n_j}$ to be $1$, and let $a_n = 0$ for all other $n$ that are not of the form. Show that this sequence has all subsequences $\{a_{kp}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ converging to $0$ but that the special subsequence $a_{n_j}$ converges to 1 to so that the overall sequence $a_n$ is not convergent.