# Convergence of subsequences for every prime $p$, does it mean convergence of the sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Just a curious thought of mine. Let $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence.

Suppose for every prime $p$, $(x_{pn})_{n\geq1}$ converges to the same limit say $a$, could we say therefore that $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converges to $a$ too?

Obviously this would imply that for every natual number $m$ $(x_{mn})_{n\geq1}$ converges to the same limit but what to do next? It feels like I might be going down the black hole of selecting the maximum of an infinite set of positive integers.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint : Every integer $N>1$ is divisible by some prime $p$ , so what can you conclude for $x_n$ with sufficiently large $n$ ?

Comment: Here is a counterexample: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3149558/42969, also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1921567/42969

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/734323/42969 ?

Comment: @MartinR Nice! Thanks! I am marking it as a duplicate

Comment: @Peter Hey Peter thanks for the input, I am not so sure what could we conclude, could you please explain a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: All those similar questions were found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(x_%7Bp%20n%7D)%24%2C%20AND%20content%3Aprime%2C%20AND%20content%3Aconvergent)

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! I do have another question, if we drop the condition of primality, and instead focusing on every natural number that is not $1$, could this statement be true? I couldnt find much in the Approach0 site sadly

Comment: @JustWandering: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1921565/42969

Comment: @MartinR Wow what a great counter example! Did you still find this via the above linked site? (just genuinely out of curiosity)